# how to get the jquery animate method to slide left?

Tags: jquery

how to get the jquery animate method to slide left?

For example, I have list of items i get from an ajax call. The list of items are placed into ul li list..

```
           <ul id="list">
               <li>aaaa</li>
               <li>bbbb</li>
               <li>cccc</li>
               <li>dddd</li>
               <li>eeee</li>
          </ul>
```

Now I'm trying to animate this list into a div called insertDataDiv

```
 <div id="insertDataDiv">
       <ul id="list"></ul>
 </div>
```

Here is the sliding logic I'm having problems with.

Once the data has been inserted into the div I then animated it

```
var startSlideFrom = $("#insertDataDiv").position().left + $("#insertDataDiv").width();
var moveSlideTo = "0%";

$("#list").css({marginLeft: startSlideFrom});  // this is working
$("#list").animate({marginLeft: moveSlideTo}); // this is working
```

Further down in the code, I attempt to move the previous list items out of the insertDataDiv like this:

```
  startSlideFrom = moveSlideTo;

  $("#list").css({marginLeft: startSlideFrom}); 
  $("#list").animate({marginLeft: "-100"});
```

This last line correctly slides to the left but the new list slide in from the right looping back to top should slide from the left again as the first list did.

what I'm trying to accomplish is this...

```
               -------------------------
 <- slide out  |   insertDataDiv        | <-- slide in the list from position 408
               -------------------------
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear.  Everything makes sense, until you get to the part where you say "....but the new list slide in from the right...".  *What new list?*  What do you mean "looping back" ?  Take one step back and explain more clearly what visual effect you are trying to achieve.  When you say "what I'm trying to accomplish..."  - you *HAVE* accomplished that, right?  Your code says "this is working" in the comments.  So.... what's the problem?